# The name 'File' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net

I am a beginner in c# programming. I am gettting error `The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`.

Problem must be in the line  `var v = File.ReadLines("dictionary.txt");`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                var v = File.ReadLines("dictionary.txt");
```

Comment: please, don't downvote. He is a beginner. Dovydas, you would get the answer to your question checking the hint that Visual Studio offers in the intellisense. This hint, linked to the error, tells you that you may be missing an include. It will probalby even tell you what to include.

Comment: Simply Add System.IO...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add this using statement to the top of you file

```
using System.IO;
```

The compiler only recognises classes from namespaces that you have in the current context. You add namespace to the context using `using` statements. You can also use a fully qualified type name such as `System.IO.File` to refer to the class.

If you are using Visual Studio you can also place the cursor on the problematic symbol (`File`) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: Thank you appreciate your help!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, added using statement but no luck. Should I add any nuget packages for getting using `System.IO;`?

Comment: That should not be needed. But you need a reference to the assembly containing the class. It's normally added automatically. Create a new project and see what references it had. 

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using Visual Studio 2015 this error will still occur even if System.IO is referenced. The problem is that by default a Visual Studio 2015 project will target both the dnx451 and dnxcore50 frameworks, and the System.IO assembly doesn't seem to be available for dnxcore50.

If you look in the project.json file you'll see a "frameworks" section. The quick fix is to comment out the "dnxcore50" entry so that you're only targeting dnx451:

```
"dnxcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `using System.IO;` to your usings section.

`File` class is located in `System.IO` namespace.

Alternatively (if it is the only place in your code where you're using some type from `System.IO`) you can use fully qualified name of `File` like:

```
var v = System.IO.File.ReadLines("dictionary.txt");
```

But in the case when you need to access objects from some namespace multiple times in your code, it is better to inculde that namespace in usings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `System.IO` add `using System.IO` next to other usings.

Comment: Hi need to add any NuGet packages for getting `using System.IO;`? Facing the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Add a using statement:

```
using System.IO
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working .Net Core in vs2017 and I have a similar problem.

> To solve this problem you should change the target framework and install System.IO.FileSystem.

Using the following methods:

- Right click the project and select properties.
- in Application Tab and Target Framework section change to .NetStandard1.6

Then, To install System.IO.FileSystem, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package System.IO.FileSystem -Version 4.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1.In here first we need to create the object like this.

```
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
```

2.Then you need to add this top of your code

```
 using System.IO;
```

3.Finally you can change your code like this

```
OpenFileDialog.Title -----> ofd.Title
OpenFileDialog.Filter -----> ofd.Filter
```